# Git - Checkout specific boost version fails ("Not a git repository")

Tags: git, boost, window, git-submodules

I want to integrate boost in my local build system. The idea is to automatically retrieve a specific version of boost and build it. To improve the speed I want to keep a local cache of the boost repository. Therefore the steps would be:

1. Clone or fetch latest results if already cloned
2. Checkout the requested version
3. Build, copy, ...

Step 1 and 2 basically boil down to the following git commands

---

```
git clone --recursive -c core.longpaths=true -j 20 https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git .
git checkout --recurse-submodules tags/boost-1.65.1
```

---

The clone itself works fine but the checkout fails with the following message

---

```
fatal: Not a git repository: ../../.git/modules/libs/hana
fatal: Not a git repository: ../../.git/modules/libs/metaparse
Note: checking out 'tags/boost-1.65.1'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 436ad1dfc... Revert accidental submodule changes  in last commit
M       libs/hana
M       libs/metaparse
```

---

This is on a Windows 7 system with git 2.15.0

**Edit:**

I also tried to place the repository in a short directory tree and removed the `core.longpaths` flag. Same issue...

Comment: Did you forget to change folder to `boost`?

Comment: @Xeningem No i am cloning into the current directory - See the first command

Comment: That's strange - I ran the same command and got the same message except `fatal:` lines. Win 10, git version 2.13.2.windows

`HEAD is now at 436ad1dfc... Revert accidental submodule changes  in last commit`
But without modified `libs/hana` and `libs/metaparse`

Comment: @Xeningem Hm may I ask which git distribution you use? This one https://git-scm.com ?

Comment: actually I didn't install git alone, just installed Git Extensions  https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions (2.50.02) which has nice GUI and ability to run git bash from context menu in any place.

Comment: @Xeningem Hm okay and they use https://git-for-windows.github.io - Which doesn't work either for me... Maybe it is a Windows 7 issue!?

Comment: This is still happening in 2023 on Linux Ubuntu